# vpnc debian configuration for isakmp

Tags: linux, debian, vpn, isakmp

i need to connect site-to-site VPN from my debian server

i have hosts, peer and isakmp key

how should i configure vpnc to use isakmp ?

or if you can point me to good vpnc documentation which i wasn't able to find
or some other tutorial
all tutorials which i saw was username password configuration
but only information the other part provided was hosts (some local ips), peek and isakmp key

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do the results of the following websites not help you with your setup processes. debian has great wki information and there are other sites with lots of otehr great information as a fallback you can always check ubuntu documents normally getting things that dont work are minor adjusments

http://wiki.debian.org/IPsec

[IPSec How-to Debian](http://ramnik.net/wp/?p=3)

[Ubuntu IPSecHowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IPSecHowTo)